# How do I properly handle 'NaN' value in input type='number' in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, input

Just creating a simple currency converter (React + Typescript).

Everything works good. But I'm bit misunderstanding 1 thing: how to clear input (where you enter amount of money) dynamically properly?

Code:

```
const App = () => {
  
  ...

  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1)
  const [amountInFromCurrency, setAmountInFromCurrency] = useState(true)
  

  let fromAmount, toAmount
  if (amountInFromCurrency) {
    fromAmount = amount
    toAmount = parseFloat((amount * exchangeRate).toFixed(2))
  } else {
    toAmount = amount
    fromAmount = parseFloat((amount / exchangeRate).toFixed(2))
  }

  
  return (

    <Card 
      amount={fromAmount}
    />
    <Card 
      amount={toAmount}
    />

  )
}

const Card = ({  amount }) => {
  return (

   <input type="number" value={amount || 0} onChange={changeInput}/>

  )
}
```

When I start clean the input to the end it becomes 0 in both inputs as expected. But when I start entering the numbers in the input after cleaning it (when it shows 0) they start appearing after 0 but not instead. Example: shows "0", I start entering the numbers, shows "0123" instead "123". The 0 disapears only if I highlight all the numbers with cursor and enter another number or it disappears if I push inner/outer-spin-buttons in input.

As you can see my approach here for input value is `value={amount || 0}`. If I put only `value={amount}` the mistake that 'You have NaN in value' appears when I clean input to the end. I don't need that mistake.

What I need: cleaning inputs fully without mistake or if I show 0 after cleaning I need to disapper it correctly when I start entering other numbers like "123" but not "0123"

UPDATE:

Code for input change:

```
  const handleFromAmountChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setAmount(parseInt(e.target.value))
    setAmountInFromCurrency(true)
  }

  const handleToAmountChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setAmount(parseInt(e.target.value))
    setAmountInFromCurrency(false)
  }
```

Comment: modify your `changeInput` function to check if the first character is a 0, and the second character is numeric -- if it is, have the value change to the same string without the leading 0

Comment: You should show a reproducible example, you don't show how you "clean the input" using `changeInput`. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: NaN is a result of the calls to parseFloat.  You could check if amount/exchangeRate are valid before doing math on them.

Comment: It works for me if I use `value={amount + ""}` for the input.

Comment: @Chris G, works but shows warning `The specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.`

Comment: That means you need to make sure that your state variables never end up being NaN in the first place.

Comment: @Chris G, how to do it properly in my case?

Comment: @Chris G, understood, thx, just did `value={ amount ? amount : " " }`